# How to count Observation between two dates

Tags: python, datetime

I have data in DateTime format. I need to calculate the number of observations between two dates.
My approach is like this:

```
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta 

names = ["year","month","day","hour","minute","second"]
df1 = pd.read_csv('T.txt',sep='\t',names=names)
df2 = pd.read_csv('Axil.txt',sep='\t',names=names)
t_series1=pd.to_datetime(df1[names]) # Time series 1
t_series2=pd.to_datetime(df2[names]) # time series 2
t1=t_series1[0] # first entry of time series1 
t2=t1+ timedelta(hours=2) # 
print(t_series1)
print(t_series2)
```

## I tried this but there is an error

```
uu=t_series2.datetime.between_time('t1', 't2')
print(uu)
```

And the date is looking like this: time series 1(length 164) and time series 2(length 145261)

```
0     2015-02-13 19:30:00
1     2015-02-16 23:38:00
2     2015-03-30 00:33:00
3     2015-04-24 13:59:00
4     2015-04-25 07:04:00
              ...        
159   2021-01-21 13:13:00
160   2021-01-24 00:41:00
161   2021-02-03 06:09:00
162   2021-02-10 14:05:00
163   2021-02-13 14:40:00
Length: 164, dtype: datetime64[ns]
0        2015-01-22 00:00:28
1        2015-01-22 00:08:59
2        2015-01-22 02:02:41
3        2015-01-22 02:19:57
4        2015-01-22 02:36:07
                 ...        
145256   2021-02-28 01:42:40
145257   2021-02-28 01:49:45
145258   2021-02-28 02:27:24
145259   2021-02-28 10:00:36
145260   2021-02-28 13:58:12
Length: 145261, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `between_time` selects observations between particular times of a day (see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between_time.html)). To get the number of observations between dates, you can try

```
((t_series2>=t1)&(t_series2<=t2)).sum()
```

Alternatively, you could convert the `names` column in your `DataFrame`s to `datetime`, set it as a `DateTimeIndex` then use `loc`:

```
df1['names'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.names)
df1.set_index('names', inplace=True)
df1.loc[t1:t2].shape[0]  # returns the length of the sub-frame of observations between t1 and t2
```

Comment: Thanks for such a great suggestion. This helps me a lot to solve my problems.